Postfix. Письма приходят не на тот сервер
Сделал почтовый сервер на Postfix для работы с двумя доменами: domain1.ru и domain2.ru. DNS записи у регистраторов прописал, создал почтовые ящики у этих доменов, всё работает.
Пришлось domain2.ru перенести на сервер MAIL.RU (создал такие же имена). DNS записи у регистраторов прописал, почтовые ящики работают. На своем сервере в панели управления Postfix сделал domain2.ru неактивным. Пользователи domain2.ru заходят на мой сервер чтобы смотреть старые письма, а сами уже работают через MAIL.RU.
Но возникла проблема: Если писать с почты domain1.ru на почту domain2.ru, то письма попадают на мой сервер, а не на сервер MAIL.RU.
Пробовал в /etc/postfix/main.cf вместо
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain

написать
mydestination =

но не помогло.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить.
